# jQuery Crossfade Plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build or implement a headline/image rotator.  The user will click on a number (1, 2, 3) and an image will fade out/fade in as well as make a headline change(some text in a span element) based on the number selected.

Is there a plugin existing that will do this?  If not, what would be the best way to accomplish this using jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: so what you want is a user to click on 1 and the image that corresponds to 1 will fade in then fade out, and the same with 2 and 3, but different images..right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

Comment: The pager on this page: http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/int2.html is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at this:

[jQuery for Designers: Image Cross Fade](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-cross-fade-transition/)

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do this is to append all the images into your document, hide them, and then $().fadeIn() them one by one and hide them.

actually, there is probably already a plugin that does this.

Comment: That wouldn't result in Crossfade.