# images fade in/out

Tags: jquery, animation, fadein, fadeout

I have this 2 images classes for a menu (img.b and img.a) superimposing, img.b lay above by default and with 0 transparency, and i need to make img.a fade out while the other fade in.. like the code i have, img.a remain under the one that fade in (the 2 classes have transparency so you can see them one over the other).. tried several solutions but i ended up affecting all the buttons together.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img.b").hover(
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "fast");
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "fast");
});
});
</script>


img.a {
    z-index: 1;
    position:absolute;
        }

img.b {
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index:10;
    }
```

Comment: Hover in this form has been removed from jQuery 1.9+

Comment: Use [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

Comment: can you please edit your question as the actual question/issue is unclear to me as it stands

Comment: ok practically the img.b fade in above img.a (which can be visible under).. cant make img.a fade out while imb.b fade in, hope its clearer

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - Are you sure that `.hover()` has been removed?  They said `"hover" pseudo-event`, not function: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#hover-pseudo-event

Comment: the code like that is working actually, well not in the way i want but working

Comment: @Axel Thus my comment "in this form" as that is what that means.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss "in this form", I'm assuming you're referring to his question...which isn't using the depreciated pseudo-event.  The code in his question has not been depreciated in jQuery 1.9+ as you suggest.  He is using `.hover()`, not `.on('hover')`

Comment: This form is fine. http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745853/how-do-i-make-fade-transition-crossfade).  What you are trying to do is called cross fading.  [This article](http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade/) explains it quite well.

You may also be interested in [crossfading with CSS](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/).

The real issue is that it is difficult to actually do a true cross fade in JavaScript due to it's single thread. All the 'cross fade' plugins etc. fake it by either only fading out the top element or by flashing through the background real fast. i.e fadeOut one image in 500ms showing the background for a half millisecond then immediately fadeIn the new image over 500ms.

If you have two images with transparency, doing a nice cross fade is going to be very difficult without using the faux-cross-fade-via-the-background technique.

It may be possible to get a true cross fade using some [canvas and requestAnimationFrame](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2011/08/crossfading-with-canvas.html) but that's getting far more complicated than a simple jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut call.

Comment: thanks, i'll be trying to solve the problem in a different way so