# fade images in and out on mouseover...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html and js. It switches from one image to to the other fine. But I'd like the images to fade in and fade out (cross fade? is that the term?). I did a search but haven't been able to adapt the other fade methods into mine for some reason. How can I accomplish this?

```
<li class="item">
    <a href="/link.html" class="gallery-item">
        <span>
            <img src="/pic1-1.jpg" data-hover="pic1-2.jpg" width="243" height="243" />
        </span>
    </a>   
</li>
```

Javascript below

```
$(function () {
    $('.item img').each(function () {
        $(this).data('original', this.src)
    }).mouseenter(function () {
        $(this)
            .attr('src', $(this).data('hover'))
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this)
            .attr('src', $(this).data('original'))
    })

})
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9qGtv/52/

Thanks!

Comment: So you could not get `$(this).stop().fadeTo(500,.5);` to work? Or just with CSS: http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/

Comment: Do you want fade out -> switch image -> fade in, or do you want one image to fade out at the same time the other fades in?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745853/how-do-i-make-fade-transition-crossfade

Comment: Nope. It still abruptly changes from one image to the other. And also introduces a weird white overlay.

Comment: Jason, ideally I'd like one image to fade in at the same time the other fades out.

Comment: You mean in and out in one function or Mouse over = In, Mouse out = Out

Comment: @user2747609 Then see the duplicate that mhu posted.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/SuZQ8/

Change your javascript to this.  If you would like to have them fade without the pause you will want to have both images present in the DOM as you can't fade the switching of a source;

```
$(function () {
    $('.item img').each(function () {
        $(this).data('original', this.src);
    }).mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(500, function(){
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('hover'));
            $(this).fadeIn(500);
        });
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(500, function(){
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('original'));
            $(this).fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can the fade in and fade out happen simultaneously? Or can the second image just fade in and out on top of the first?

Answer (score 0):

**Pure CSS**

**HTML**:

```
<span class="imageContainer">
     <img src="/pic1-1.jpg" width="243" height="243"  class="staticimage" />
     <img src="/pic1-2.jpg" width="243" height="243"  class="hoverimage"/>
</span>
```

**CSS**:

```
.staticimage
{
  position:relative;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  transition:1s;
}

.hoverimage
{
  position:relative;
  left:0px;
  top:0px; 
  display:none;
  transition:1s;
}

.imageContainer:hover .staticimage
{
  display:none;
  transition:1s;
}

.imageContainer:hover .hoverimage
{
  display:inline-block;
  transition:1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is already 4 years old, I thought I'll add my solution. Based on Mark's answer, this is my approach:

```css
.gallery-item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 243px;
  height: 243px;
}

.staticimage,
.hoverimage {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hoverimage {
  opacity: 0;
}

.gallery-item:hover .hoverimage {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="/link.html" class="gallery-item">
  <div style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/250/?random')" class="staticimage"></div>
  <div style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/251/?random')" class="hoverimage"></div>
</a>
```